# How to only use the lower bounds and upper bounds for quadratic solver qpsolve from Scilab?

Tags: constraints, scilab, quadratic-programming, control-theory

I have a simple question. How do I use the command qpsolve from Scilab if I only want to use the lower bounds and upper bounds limit?

```
   ci  <= x <= cs
```

The command can be used as this:

```
   [x [,iact [,iter [,f]]]] = qpsolve(Q,p,C,b,ci,cs,me)
```

But I want to use it like this:

```
   x = qpsolve(Q,p,[],[],ci,cs,[])
```

Only ci and cs should explain the limits for vector x. Unfortunately, the command cannot take empty []. Should I take [] as a row vector of ones or zeros?

https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.1/en_US/qpsolve.html

Comment: Try C,b as zeros(x) and me = 0.

Comment: You sure that it will work?

Comment: No I'm not, i didn't check, but looking at the doc, it is equivalent to a bound-constrained optimization problem.

Comment: @PTRK Ok! I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scilab 5.5.1 , `[]` works for C and b but not for `me`.  so `C = [];b = [];me = 0;` should work.

## Why

qpsolve is an interface for qp_solve :

```
function [x, iact, iter, f]=qpsolve(Q,p,C,b,ci,cs,me)

    rhs = argn(2);
    if rhs <> 7
        error(msprintf(gettext("%s: Wrong number of input argument(s): %d expected.\n"), "qpsolve", 7));
    end
    C(me+1:$, :) = -C(me+1:$, :);
    b(me+1:$) = -b(me+1:$);
    // replace boundary contraints by linear constraints
    Cb = []; bb = [];
    if ci <> [] then
        Cb = [Cb; speye(Q)]
        bb = [bb; ci]
    end
    if cs <> [] then
        Cb = [Cb; -speye(Q)]
        bb = [bb; -cs]
    end
    C = [C; Cb]; b = [b; bb]
    [x, iact, iter, f] = qp_solve(Q, -p, C', b, me)

endfunction
```

It transform every bound constraints into linear constraints. To begin, it swap the sign of the inequality constraints. To do that, it must know `me`, ie it must be an integer. Since `C` and `b` are empty matrices, is value doesn't matter.

## Bonus:

if `Q` is inversible, you could skip the `qpsolve` macro and write

```
x = -Q\p
x(x<ci) = ci(x<ci)
x(x>cs) = cs(x>cs)
```

Comment: for me, this works: x = qp_solve(eye(n,n), v(n,1), zeros(n, 1), [0], 0), where v is a vector of dimension n.